# Why can't javascript/jQuery get parentNode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

Considering that I have an element like this:

```
<p class="ELP">2/1/2013 - <a id="EL3" class="ELLink" href="/Event htms/Event.cshtml?title=Okmulgee Public Schools County Professional Day&amp;explanation=Okmulgee Public Schools County Professional Day.&amp;dateString=2-1-2013">City Public Schools County Professional Day</a></p>
```

Why does this JavaScript/jQuery work...:

```
$(".ELP").click(function (){
        var stringDate = $(this).text().substring(0, 8)
        console.log(stringDate)
    });
```

**Console.log produces:  2/1/2013**

...And this JavaScript/jQuery doesn't?

```
$(".ELLink").click(function (){
        var stringDate = $(this).parentNode.text().substring(0, 8)
        console.log(stringDate)
    });
```

**Console.log produces nothing because of JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'text' of undefined**

Clearly I can see that it is not 'getting' the right element, but why? Isn't the first parent node of my 'a' element the 'p' element? As far as I understand it, there is no (at least no cross-browser/platform compatible) valid css selector for the direct parent node of an element or i would just use that.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: jQuery objects don't have a `parentNode` property. try using the `.parent()` method instead.

Comment: use `parent()` instead of `parentNode`

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys, every search I did on this referred JavaScript parentNode property. Didn't really see the way jQuery implements this, but I get it now, thanks to all of you. But you would think I would have gotten some information on the parent() method. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jQuery method is called parent()

```
$(".ELLink").click(function (){
        var stringDate = $(this).parent().text().substring(0, 8)
        console.log(stringDate)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I didn't see that method.

Answer (score 1):

Because the jQuery object does not have a parentNode property.

```
var stringDate = $(this.parentNode).text().substring(0, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(...)` does not return DOM elements, it returns an array-like object that references DOM nodes. DOM nodes have `parentNode`. jQuery instances do not.

If you need to select the immediate parents of the selected elements, you can use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent):

```
$(this).parent().text()...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
var stringDate = $(this).parent().text().substring(0, 8)
```

Since you're already using jQuery, you can use the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parent()` not `parentNode`. Like this:

```
$(".ELLink").click(function (){
    var stringDate = $(this).parent().text().substring(0, 8)
    console.log(stringDate)
});
```